# How cant test Query, Mutation, Subscription services using Apollo Angular?

Tags: angular, apollo-client, apollo-angular

I saw the examples of how [testing apollo in angular](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/guides/testing/#apollotestingmodule) works and basically only use the [ApolloTestingModule](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/guides/testing/#apollotestingmodule) to make the tests. And my test looks like:

## Test suit

```js
describe('CountriesService', () => {
  let countryService: CountriesService;
  let controller: ApolloTestingController;
  let scheduler: TestScheduler;
  let countries: any;

  beforeAll(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ApolloTestingModule],
    });

    countries = [{ code: 'C1', phone: '500', name: 'Country' }];
    scheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });
    countryService = TestBed.inject(CountriesService);
    controller = TestBed.inject(ApolloTestingController);
  });

  test('should be created', () => {
    expect(countryService).toBeTruthy();
  });

  test('should return an array of countries', () => {
    countryService.watch().valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);

    const operation = controller.expectOne(COUNTRIES_GQL);
    operation.flush({ data: { countries } });

    controller.verify();
  });
});
```

## Service

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CountriesService {
  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}

  watch() {
    return this.apollo.watchQuery({
      query: COUNTRIES_GQL,
    });
  }
}
```

## Problem

I want to use the approach of using  [Query, Mutation, Subscription service](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/services/) but with this approach the test doesn't work.

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CountriesService extends Query<any> {
  document = COUNTRIES_GQL;
}
```

## Error

```sh
● CountriesService › should return an array of countries

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined

      30 | 
      31 |   test('should return an array of countries', () => {
      32 |     countryService.watch().valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);
         |                    ^
      33 | 
      34 |     const operation = controller.expectOne(COUNTRIES_GQL);
      35 |     operation.flush({ data: { countries } });
```

For me the error makes sense because in the official implementation of [Query class](https://github.com/kamilkisiela/apollo-angular/blob/master/packages/apollo-angular/src/Query.ts) the methods fetch and watch are using the **use method** provided by Apollo service.

## Questions

- Does an alternative to test this type of service provided by apollo ?
- If I want to use this approach, I should test it as a basic service?

I wait for your answers

Answer (score 0):

try to instance ur service 
and call it with the `methode countryService.watch()`
 then

```
countryService.watch().valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: I don't understand, because that line of code is the same that I have in the test suit

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working using this approach mocking the service in providers (does not use AppolloTestingModule). Made a helper function `graphQlServiceMock` for reuse across all services.

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
       provide: MyGQLService,
       useValue: graphQlServiceMock({ users: null }),
    },
  ]

})
```

```js
export const graphQlServiceMock = (response: any) => ({
  watch: () => ({
    valueChanges: of({
      data: {
        ...response,
      },
      loading: false,
    }),
  }),
});
```

or without helper..

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...
  providers: [
  {
    provide: MyGQLService,
    useValue: {
      watch: () => ({
        valueChanges: of({
          data: {
            users: null,
          },
          loading: false,
        }),
      }),
    },
  },
 ];
})
```

Comment: sorry i saw `watch` and thought you were using the newer generated services method (https://apollo-angular.com/docs/data/services), if not then my code may not apply for you :)